# Почему ломается миксин при замене var на let?

Tags: pug

Заменил в коде все var на let и все работает, кроме этого миксина. Тут почему-то все ломается.

```html
mixin dropdown(params)
  .dropdown(class=`js-${params.type}`)
    .dropdown__caption
      h3.dropdown__caption-left= params.leftCaption
      if (params.rightCaption)
        h3.dropdown__caption-right= params.rightCaption
    .dropdown__block.js-dropdown__block(class=params.menuStatus)
      .dropdown__block_top.js-dropdown__block_top(data-dd-action="showHide" tabindex="0")
        p.dropdown__selection_text.js-dropdown__selection-text(data-dd-action="showHide")= params.selectionText
        .dropdown__expand-button.material-icons(data-dd-action="showHide") expand_more

      .dropdown__menu.js-dropdown__menu(hidden=params.expMenuStatus)

        if (params.type == "dropdown-options")
          - var items = { "item1": {valName : "Спальни", vName: "bedrooms"},"item2": {valName : "Кровати", vName: "beds"},"item3": {valName : "Ванные комнаты", vName: "bathrooms"} };
          if (params.idPostfix == "-changed-example")
            - var items = { "item1": {valName : "Спальни", vName: "bedrooms", valCounter: "2", valClass: "dark"},"item2": {valName : "Кровати", vName: "beds", valCounter: "2", valClass: "dark"},"item3": {valName : "Ванные комнаты", vName: "bathrooms"} };

        // почему при замене любого из четырех следующих var ломается миксин?
        if (params.type == "dropdown-guests")
          - var items = { "item1": {valName : "Взрослые", vName: "adults"},"item2": {valName : "Дети", vName: "childs"},"item3": {valName : "Младенцы", vName: "babies"} };
          if (params.idPostfix == "-changed-example")
            - var items = { "item1": {valName : "Взрослые", vName: "adults", valCounter: "2", valClass: "dark"},"item2": {valName : "Дети", vName: "childs", valCounter: "1", valClass: "dark"},"item3": {valName : "Младенцы", vName: "babies"} };

        //- form(action='change-me')
        if (params.formPart === 'true')
          each val, key in items
            .dropdown__menu-option(class=key)
              p.dropdown__item= val.valName
              .dropdown__item-controls.js-dropdown__item-controls
                button.dropdown__button-decrement.js-dropdown__button-decrement(tabindex="0" class=val.valClass data-dd-action="decrement" type="button")
                input.dropdown__counter.js-dropdown__counter(tabindex="-1" name=val.vName value=val.valCounter || 0)
                button.dropdown__button-increment(tabindex="0" data-dd-action="increment" type="button")
        else
          form(action='change-me')
            each val, key in items
              .dropdown__menu-option(class=key)
                p.dropdown__item= val.valName
                .dropdown__item-controls.js-dropdown__item-controls
                  button.dropdown__button-decrement.js-dropdown__button-decrement(tabindex="0" class=val.valClass data-dd-action="decrement" type="button")
                  input.dropdown__counter.js-dropdown__counter(tabindex="-1" name=val.vName value=val.valCounter || 0)
                  button.dropdown__button-increment(tabindex="0" data-dd-action="increment" type="button")

        //- dropdown buttons for dropdown-guests
        if (params.type == "dropdown-guests")
          .dropdown-guests__buttons
            if (params.cleanButtonStatus == "show")
              - let cleanButtonClass = "dropdown-guests__button_clean_"+params.cleanButtonStatus

            button.dropdown-guests__button_clean.js-dropdown-guests__button_clean(tabindex="0" class=cleanButtonClass data-dd-action="clean" type="button") очистить
            button.dropdown-guests__button_apply.js-dropdown-guests__button_apply(tabindex="0" data-dd-action="apply" type="button") применить
```

вот такая ошибка в webpack при сборке, для всех страниц где есть этот миксин

```
    ERROR in ./src/pages/search-room.pug (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/pages/search-room.pug)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/pug-loader/index.js):
    Error: Error parsing body of the with expression
        at addWith (~/node_modules/with/lib/index.js:50:29)
        at Compiler.compile (~/node_modules/pug-code-gen/index.js:139:12)
        at generateCode (~/node_modules/pug-code-gen/index.js:32:37)
        at compileBody (~/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:199:74)
        at Object.exports.compileClientWithDependenciesTracked (~/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:317:16)
        at Object.exports.compileClient (~/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:363:18)
        at run (~/node_modules/pug-loader/index.js:136:23)
        at ~/node_modules/pug-loader/index.js:61:7
        at ~/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/LoaderPlugin.js:105:17
        at Semaphore.acquire (~/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/Semaphore.js:29:4)
        at ~/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/LoaderPlugin.js:69:31
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

Не пойму куда копать

Comment: А зачем заменили? Разве в доках Pug что-то сказано про `let`?

Comment: Задача избавиться от var в pug файлах. Видел где-то на стеке, сейчас не могу найти, видимо, это было тоже в вопросе.